# What are some elementary books which discuss projective lines on surfaces with examples?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, cubics, abelian-varieties

I have the books: 
W. H. Blythe, On models of cubic surfaces (1905) and
A. Henderson, The twenty-seven lines upon the cubic surface,
and a couple more modern algebraic geometry books including I. R. Shafarevich, Basic algebraic geometry 1, which discusses lines on cubic surfaces but without examples of the lines. I would like to know about some books where I can learn classical algebraic geometry treating lines on surfaces which are more recent than the first two books I mention and have examples exhibiting the actual lines.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is as explicit as what you want, but the draft book on intersection theory by Eisenbud and Harris that is floating around the web talks about Fano schemes a lot; it's certainly a modern treatment. The new-ish book *Classical Algebraic Geometry* by Dolgachev might be an even better fit, although I haven't read any of it.

Comment: Maybe you should search for an intersection theory book. I think you want to understand the Chow ring of a cubic. You may want to study Schubert calculus too. I think this is a good reference http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf . It's not exactly classical. There are some recent books on classical algebraic geometry (from EMS and Springer but I don't remember the name), but I don't know them well.

Comment: @user40276 Thanks for posting the link I was too lazy to provide. Harris is teaching the course again this coming semester so hopefully a new version will appear.

Comment: Thank you both for the recommendation and the link.